# Mutation not resolving until called again

Tags: typescript, react-native, promise, react-apollo, graphcool

I am creating a React Native application and am using basic email/password auth supplied by Graphcool. I trigger the mutation when pressing the 'Log in' button. On the first press of the button the code within the `then` callback never is executed; On the second press of the button the `then` callback is executed twice immediately and I am sent to my 'app' screen.

Could there be something wrong with my configuration? Am I doing something incorrectly? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I attempted to reduce code to only which is applicable for this issue.

Code:

```
export type ILoginFormProps = LoginFormComponentProps & QueryProps & LoginFormApolloProps;

interface LoginFormComponentProps {
    err: object,
    saveUser(id: string, email: string, token: string);
    loginFailed(err: object);
}

interface LoginFormApolloProps {
    client: ApolloClient,
    signInUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any>;
}

export interface ILoginFormState {
    email: string,
    password: string,
    isRegister: boolean;
    loading: boolean;
}

class LoginForm extends Component<ILoginFormProps, ILoginFormState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            isRegister: false,
            loading: false
        }
    }

    onLoginSuccess({ data }): void {
        console.log(data);
        const { token } = data.signinUser;
        AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token).then(() => client.resetStore());
        Actions.app();
    }

    onLogin() {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        this.props.signInUser(
            this.state.email,
            this.state.password
        ).then(({ data }) => { 
          console.log(data);
          const { token } = data.signinUser;
          AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token).then(() => client.resetStore());
          Actions.app();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            this.props.loginFailed(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(239,204,143,0.5)' }}>
                <Content style={{ opacity: 1 }}>
                    <Form style={{ marginBottom: 25 }}>
                        <Item>
                            <Input
                                placeholder='Email'
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChangeText={(text: string) => {
                                    this.setState({ email: text });
                                }}
                            />
                        </Item>
                        <Item last>
                            <Input
                                placeholder='Password'
                                value={this.state.password}
                                onChangeText={(text: string) => {
                                    this.setState({ password: text });
                                }}
                                secureTextEntry
                            />
                        </Item>
                    </Form>
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.onLogin.bind(this)}
                        style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10 }}
                        block
                    >
                        <Text>Log In</Text>
                    </Button>
                </Content>
            </Container >
        );
    }
}

const SignInUserMutation = gql`
  mutation signInUser($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    signinUser(
      email: {
        email: $email,
        password: $password
      }
    ){
        token,
    }
  }`

const withSignIn = withApollo(graphql<LoginFormApolloProps, LoginFormComponentProps, ILoginFormProps>(
    SignInUserMutation, {
        props: ({ mutate }) => ({
            signInUser: (email, password) => mutate({ variables: { email, password } })
        })
    })(withUserCreated));

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => {
    const { err } = auth;
    return { err };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    saveUser,
    loginFailed,
})(withSignIn);
```

Using this code. If I press 'Log In', nothing occurs and nothing prints to the debugger console. When I press 'Log In' a second time, I get two `console.log`'s printing out the proper response from Apollo.

Comment: This ended up being an error with the version of react-native I was using. It has been fixed in v0.47

Comment: Nice, [could you answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and mark this as solved? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a problem with the version of React Native I was using and has been resolved as of v0.47. A detailed version of the problem can be found at [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6679) on the React Native repository on GitHub.